# Is it possible to create support for tab button in html textarea with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, tabs

I hate when I try to edit html in textarea, because it doesn't recognize tab button, so I cannot indent my code. So is it possible to generate tab support to textareas with html? And is it possible to create support for tab button with JavaScript?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105452/catching-tabs-in-textarea , which gives a solution using onkeydown.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a tutorial that explains the process very well.

http://ajaxian.com/archives/handling-tabs-in-textareas

Comment: Link does not work anymore

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the key code in `keyUp` or `keyDown` events against the tab key code: `11`.