# HTML text-area editor for code that traps TAB key

Tags: javascript, html, editor, tabs

I have looked for months now, for JavaScript-based HTML editor I can embed onto my web pages to replace a TEXTAREA, but to enable me to edit CODE in a friendly, closer to a real editor, way. All editors I've tried (RadEditor from Telerik, FCKEditor, TinyMCE, etc etc), do not trap the TAB key, very useful when editing HTML code onto a page, to help format the code properly. I'm not talking about syntax highlighting, as that would be an awesome plus. But I am mainly wondering if there is such an editor.

I'd appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362/capturing-tab-key-in-text-box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[code mirror](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/), which is used by jsbin. and it does syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

[Ace](http://ace.ajax.org) looks pretty good. It's used in the [Cloud9 IDE.](https://c9.io/)