# Key event not firing

Tags: jquery

My Javascript:

```
$("#test").keypress(function(e){
       if (document.all){ var evt = event.keyCode; }
       else if(e.which) { var evt = e.which;       }           
       else             { var evt = e.charCode;    }

       if (evt == 13){ // with any other key, the alert dos not fire
            alert(evt);
       }
       return true;
});
```

[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cDVek/6/)

The keycode 13 `Enter` fires the alert, but any other dosent.

Can any one tell me why?

I need to verify if the 13 or 9 `tab` was fired.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `keydown` rather than `keypress`

```
$('#test').live('keydown', function(e) { 
    var k = e.keyCode || e.which; 

    if (k == 9 || k == 13) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(k);
    } 
});
```

**working: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/cDVek/15/**

Comment: why if i change the 13 to 9 ( tab ) dos not fire the alert ?

Answer (score 0):

add a conditional clause to check for evt == 9:

```
if (evt == 13) { 
   alert(evt); 
} else if (evt == 9) { 
   alert(evt);
}
```

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362/capturing-tab-key-in-text-box

Comment: i see, use the "e" parameter, try: evt = e.keyCode

Comment: parameter "e" holds the "keypress" event, so use it instead of "event" (in line 2).