# How can I refer to Gmail's textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gmail, greasemonkey

I'm working on a Greasemonkey script for gmail and I need to find a way to refer to gmail's textboxes (when you compose and reply to an email). Gmail has an iframe with a new HTML and the text is in the body, as part of it's WYSIWYG editor. I've tried selecting all the classes of those elements with jquery, but they don't work -- specially, `.keypress()`

Here's what I have tried:

```
$(".editable LW-avf").keypress(function(event) {
... // the wysiwyg body
});

$(".Am Al editable").keypress(function(event) {
... // the iframe
});
```

Is there any way to bind a keypress event handler? Or is it even possible since gmail isn't a conventional textbox?

Comment: If you want to hit "reply" programatically you can write document.querySelector(".ams").click() ... Don't know if that answers your question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to hit the reply button - what I want to do is prevent the tab key from tabbing out, so I'll need to bind the keypress listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(".editable LW-avf")` would select **not** `<body class="editable LW-avf">`.

It would select something like:

```
<div class="editable">
    <LW-avf></LW-avf>
</div>
```

If that existed.

You want:

```
$("body.editable.LW-avf")
```

(Two classes, two dots in the selector.)

Also:

1. Make sure the script is set to run on iframes (it is by default).
2. You want to use `keydown`, not `keypress`, for your purposes.

Comment: Thank you, however event.preventDefault() does not work for the tab key - do you know how to suppress the tab key? I am doing it on keydown, and other keys works fine.

Comment: That's a different question!  The stated question is answered. For the tab key, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3362, but Gmail may block the customary fixes.

Comment: Confirmed.  Once again Gmail uses FUBAR JS, and the standard tab capture doesn't work.  Open a new question for the new problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty but it does the job:

```
document
    .querySelector(".editable")
    .contentDocument
    .querySelector(".editable")
    .onkeypress = function() { alert("jayer!"); };
```

Comment: Thank you, however event.preventDefault() does not work for the tab key - do you know how to get it working for the tab key?