# JavaScript keydown event: can I tell what element previously had focus?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

When a user was focused on a particular element when they pressed the tab key, I want to execute a particular function. But I don't want to this function to execute unless that particular element had focus when the tab key was pressed.

Is there a way to to tell what element had (has?) focus from the keydown event itself? Or should I set a `particularElementHasFocus` property in response to `onBlur` and `onFocus` events on that element?

Comment: Check out this post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362/capturing-tab-key-in-text-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.activeElement` to get current focused element. 
or 
use 
following code

```
var particularElementHasFocus  ;
$('input, textarea, button').focus(function() {
  particularElementHasFocus = this;
});

$('input, textarea, button').blur(function() {
  particularElementHasFocus = null;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery it could be done by testing the `.focus` of the element in question. With standard JS you can use `document.activeElement` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.activeElement