# Why doesn't preventDefault() stop focus change after a Tab-keypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, preventdefault

[I was fiddling with](http://jsfiddle.net/spL5r/) `preventDefault()` and must be doing something wrong.

```
$("#input").bind("keypress", function(event) {
    if(event.which == 9) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("You pressed tab.");
    }
});
```

The tab functionality isn't prevented. What's wrong with this?

Comment: What's it doing or not doing?

Comment: See the JSFiddle? No alert, and the functionality of tab remains.

Comment: Your fiddle is loading knockout but your question is labeled jQuery.

Comment: I may be wrong but i understand Prevent default prevents the action (mainly a form submit action) from occurring. I don't think it works for key presses because they don't have an action (apart from "return" which can act as a form submit for accessibility)

Comment: @j08691 I was trying knockout before, but would rather use JQ

Comment: There's a big difference between "keypress" and "keydown". A "keypress" can only be relied upon for keys that actually modify the value of the `<input>`. Chrome, for example, doesn't fire "keypress" for various ALT key combinations.

Comment: Maybe see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362/capturing-tab-key-in-text-box)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keypress` event is simply *not fired* when the Tab is pressed - this also explains why there is no alert, independent of what preventing the default may do.

Changing the code to use `keydown` allows the Tab to be caught and prevents the default focus-change (in Chrome<sup>1</sup>, anyway).

```
$("#input").bind("keydown", function(event) {
    if(event.which == 9) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I tested the above in Chrome 35 [with jQuery 1.6-2.1](http://jsfiddle.net/p65cL/); it does *not* work under the KO 3.0 library.

Comment: Chrome is all that matters, anyways.. <hatred incoming>

Comment: Yep, my mistake. Forgot I replaced JQ. Works

Answer (score 2):

Try this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/spL5r/4/).  The input loses focus when you tab.  Binding to the body fixes this.

```
$("body").on("keydown", function(event) {
if(event.which == 9) {
event.preventDefault();
    alert("You pressed tab.");
}
});
```

Comment: Is it changing the binding control or changing from keypress to keydown?

Comment: Changing keypress to keydown is the crucial part.  Also, be aware that this will fire EVERY time tab is pressed anywhere on the page.  If you don't want it to do that, you can wrap it in a container like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/spL5r/5/

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on JQuery,

> Note: as the keypress event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.
>
> This method is a shortcut for .on( "keypress", handler ) in the first two variations, and .trigger( "keypress" ) in the third.
>
> **The keypress event is sent to an element when the browser registers keyboard input. This is similar to the keydown event, except that modifier and non-printing keys** such as Shift, Esc, and delete **trigger keydown events but not keypress events**. Other differences between the two events may arise depending on platform and browser.

So in this case you are using the wrong event. Also it might have browser compatibility issues.