# iMacros keypress event

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have an iMacros code that introduces a name into an input field on a webpage , and then, by pressing the TAB key it should select the first option that appears in the results list.

For some reason the keypress event does not trigger the javascript and therefore no results are showing.

```
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#name-input" CHARS={{name}}
WAIT SECONDS=2

'Pressing tab key
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#name-input" KEY=13
```

Does anyone know why is this happening? Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362/capturing-tab-key-in-text-box) it states that part of the issue is that the Tab is used to jump to the next element, so you have to stop that behavior...

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL Thanks, though I've also tried using the Enter key. I believe I have to trigger some event. When it types inside the input, I can see responses coming from the server, but the options are not shown on the webpage.