# How to map a key TAB within a text area

Tags: angular, typescript, keyboard

I want to capture the TAB key pressed inside a text-area, which works to indent the text when the user presses

Comment: Use `tab` key code which is 9 on keypress or keydown event

Comment: Hope below link helps [Tab capture inside input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362/capturing-tab-key-in-text-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<textarea (keydown)="onTab($event)"></textarea>
```

If you want to prevent to loose focus from the text area on tab you can use below code in you ts.

```
  onTab(event) {
      console.log(event);
      if (event.key === 'Tab') {
        event.preventDefault();
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for verifying my answer. Can you please upvote too?

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea (keydown.Tab)="onKey($event)">
   ...
</textarea>
```

.ts

```
onKey(e){
   console.log(e); // key tab event
}
```